# docker-php-ext-install: command not found error while installing apcu_bc package on PHP 8

Tags: php, apache, centos7, apcu

I am trying to install APCU and I got an error:

```
mkdir -p /usr/src/php/ext/apcu && curl -fsSL        https://pecl.php.net/get/apcu | tar xvz -C "/usr/src/php/ext/apcu" --strip 1 && docker-php-ext-install apcu
```

acc to:
[Facing issues while installing apcu_bc package on PHP 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69029803/facing-issues-while-installing-apcu-bc-package-on-php-8/75371446?noredirect=1#comment132994523_75371446)

I got:

```
bash: docker-php-ext-install: command not found
```

I have got docker installed.

Comment: Are you running this command with "RUN docker-php-ext-install *"?

Comment: Will this solve your problem? - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54831388/enable-apcu-cli-on-docker-php-7-3

Comment: @JAson thanks it was helpfull. However I got APCU installed without docker.

Comment: Notice that apcu_bc is a compatibility layer for old APC API using APCU, but is a different extension. apcu_bc is only for PHP 7.

Comment: @RemiCollet - thank you - I haven't known it. I got to problem while installing Akaneo Pim - it requires PHP 8.0 and APCU to run.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. What I did was:

```
1. sudo dnf install https://rpms.remirepo.net/enterprise/remi-release-8.rpm

2. sudo yum install php-pecl-apcu

3. sudo yum install php-pear httpd-devel pcre-devel gcc make

4. #apache

sudo systemctl restart httpd
```

Found it here >> https://shouts.dev/articles/install-apcu-on-centos-rhel-8